# C# call class problems

Tags: c#

I am new in C# and I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Write a program that has 4 methods at least. The first method should
> display the instructions, second method should take the user input
> (first and last name, course name), the third method should take the
> user input (3 exams score and get its average), and the last method
> is to Display the message to the user with all the user information
> and calculated results back. Call the 4 methods in your main.

I have edit the post cause i need only to focus on the issue that i have. So i have a problem when i call DisplayCalculationAndResult method. What i am doing is creating a method to get the user input and in the other method i am printing the uer information but the method for the result it need a parameter when i call it right!? Ok i don't see why it throw a problem however i called a different method have other parameter and works >< or that because it string!?

This is what am getting

Use of unassigned local variable 'firstName'

Use of unassigned local variable 'lastName'

Use of unassigned local variable 'courseName'

someone help please.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace work3
{
    class Work3Calculatore
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            // Declare Variable
            string firstName, lastName, courseName;
           
            // calculate and Display result
            DisplayCalculationAndResult(firstName, lastName, courseName);
      

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static void AskTheUserForValues()
        {
            //string inputValue; // global variable
            string courseName, firstName, lastName; // needed in this method only
         
            Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the Your First Name: {0} ");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            //inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the Your Last Name: {0}");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            //inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the Course Name: {0}");
            courseName = Console.ReadLine();
            //inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static void DisplayCalculationAndResult(string firstName, string lastName, string courseName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" Your first name is: ");
            Console.WriteLine(" {0:N2 ", firstName);
            Console.WriteLine(" Your last name is: ");
            Console.WriteLine(" {0:N2} ", lastName);
            Console.WriteLine(" Your course is: ");
            Console.WriteLine(" {0:N2}", courseName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Those aren't classes, those are methods.  Can you describe the actual problem you're observing?  Why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: Your calls to GradeCalculation are missing a parameter (it expects a double)

Comment: Just because variables have the same name, they do not share values automagically. You are working with method-scoped (local) vars and expect them to reflect values in the (also local) variables in the main method. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Your method GradeCalculation needs an argument: side. And you don't give it an argument in your main method. I think it may be the problem.

Comment: Check your methods head: `public static double GradeCalculation(double side)` you either need a parameter, when calling that method, or remove it from the method.
I.e.: `public static double GradeCalculation()`

Comment: I just removed it and the call fixed but for the method DisplayAnd CalculateResult still have the problem

Comment: You also overwrite the value in `inputValue` before processing it. score will always be the _last_ inputValue entered and average therefore score/3 instead of the average of all three.

Comment: You give variables to `DisplayCalculationAndResult` but they have never been set. In `AskTheUserForValues` you ask these values form the user and save the values in variables with the same names as in the main method. But they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Skarali: There appear to be a variety of problems in this code.  We can appreciate that you're just getting started and are struggling.  Please focus on and describe the specific problem that has you stuck at this time.  Include whatever error message you're seeing, the line of code which shows that error, or the specific unexpected result you're getting from a particular operation.

Comment: Ok your right i fixed the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Error:**

In your `main` method you declare three variables, never assign anything to them, and then try to use them:

```
string firstName, lastName, courseName;
DisplayCalculationAndResult(firstName, lastName, courseName);
```

The error is simply telling you that you can't do that.  The variable has to be assigned a value (even if it's just `null`) before it can be used.  For example:

```
string firstName = null, lastName = null, courseName = null;
DisplayCalculationAndResult(firstName, lastName, courseName);
```

---

**Your Next Steps:**

It *looks like* you're intending to get those values from your `AskTheUserForValues` method.  However, two problems become evident:

1. You never call that method.
2. That method doesn't return anything.  It just sets its own local variables and then ends.

You can have that method return those values, likely by creating a class to hold them.  Suppose you create a separate class as a data structure for the three values (I'm guessing on a good class name, name yours appropriately):

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `AskTheUserForValues` method could return those values as an instance of that class:

```
public static Student AskTheUserForValues() // set the return type
{
    var result = new Student(); // create an instance of the object

    // populate the fields on that instance
    Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the Your First Name: {0} ");
    result.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the Your Last Name: {0}");
    result.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter the Course Name: {0}");
    result.CourseName = Console.ReadLine();

    return result; // return the instance
}
```

Then your `main` method can get the result from calling that method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = AskTheUserForValues();

    DisplayCalculationAndResult(values.FirstName, values.LastName, values.CourseName);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

As an added exercise to get familiar with the use of classes as simple data structures, from here try to modify your `DisplayCalculationAndResult` method to accept an instance of the new class instead of the three values individually.